# ¿Cómo solucionar problema con símbolo extraño en Java?

Tags: java

Así es como se ve mi netbeans:[image]

No entiendo porque aparece ese símbolo al final de cada línea de código. El programa en si corre bien, pero el símbolo es molesto. Aparece a cada archivo nuevo que creo, ya sea en Ant o en Maven. También en capa gráfica.

Ya probé reinstalando Netbeans, reiniciando la pc y cambiando el jdk. Nada de eso funcionó.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! ese simbolo se usa en los editores de texto (todos) como fin de linea.. no conozco la ide, pero debes tener una opcion para prender y apagar eso....

Comment: No sé qué versión de Netbeans tengas instalada, pero deberías poder quitar esto desde el menú: *Ver -> Mostrar / Ocultar caracteres no imprimibles* O si lo tienes en inglés: *View -> Show / Hide Non-printable Characters*. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola Joaquín, podrías decirnos si las respuestas dadas te resultaron útiles y en caso de haberlo sido marcar como aceptada la que más te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Ese carácter indica un salto de párrafo, y es un objeto no imprimible, para ocultarlo debes ir al **menú View** y desmarcar la **opción Show Non-Printable objects**.

Answer (score 1):

El carácter que se muestra en el editor `NetBeans`, es el carácter de salto de línea `¶`.

Cuando se visualiza este carácter, no afecta a tu código, pero si quieres no mostrarlo ve al menú:

`View` y desactiva la opción `Show Non-printable Characters`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]